# Eclipse RCP: Accidently added plugins that contribute to UI

Tags: user-interface, menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

So I accidently added a few plugins, whichs name I have forgotten to the runtime configuration of my application. Since then a ton of not needed contributions to the UI where made:

Help-> "Like 5 new links"

New Entry "Window"

Menu-Icon-Bar: Open Task, Create new visual class.

I'm unable to figure out what the responsible plugins are (There are about 300 plugins selected). If you happen to know which plugins make these contributions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the minimum set of plugins needed for your RCP using:

1. Open the `Run Configuration` for the RCP.
2. Go to the `Plug-ins` tab.
3. Click `Deselect All`
4. Select your plug-ins in the Workspace
5. Click `Add Required Plug-ins`

You should end up with just the plug-ins required. Use the `-clean` option on the next run to make sure the plug-ins cache data is rebuilt.